# Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz in a Complex Inner Product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Setup:** Given a complex inner product space $V$ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is
$$
|\langle x,y \rangle|\leq \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle} \sqrt{\langle y,y \rangle}.
$$
I know that the RHS is just the product of the induced norms that come from our inner product, but I don't want to pass to any properties of a norm function. I took the standard proof approach (I think?) but I'm not very comfortable with complex variables so I don't know if I'm doing any arithmetic that is invalid over $\mathbb{C}$. Any help would be appreciated!

**Proof Attempt:**
Define a function $f(t) = \langle x+ty,x+ty \rangle$. We can expand this inner product as
\begin{align*}
\langle x+ty,x+ty \rangle &= \langle x,x+ty\rangle + \langle ty,x+ty \rangle, \textrm{ linear in first arg.} \\
&=\langle x,x\rangle +\langle x,ty \rangle +\langle ty,x \rangle +\langle ty,ty \rangle, \textrm{ linear in second argument.}\\
&=\langle x,x \rangle + \overline{t} \langle x, y \rangle + t\langle y,x \rangle +t\overline{t} \langle y,y\rangle, \textrm{ conjugate linearity in second argument.}
\end{align*}
Now because $t \in \mathbb{C}$ we know that $t\overline{t} = |t|^2$. We also have by conjugate symmetry that
$$
\overline{t}\langle x,y \rangle= t \langle y,x \rangle.
$$
Now because the inner product is positive definite, we can conclude that
$$
0 \leq \langle x,x \rangle + 2\overline{t}\langle x,y \rangle +|t|^2 \langle y,y\rangle.
$$
Now just like in the case where we are over the reals, I would like to conclude by making the claim that this is a quadratic in $t$ that opens upwards, meaning it has no real roots and hence the discriminant $b^2-4ac \leq 0$ but I don't know if that's valid. It seems fair-ish because $\langle x,x \rangle$ and $\langle y,y \rangle$ are both real numbers, but is there a way to conclude that $\langle x,y \rangle $ is also a real number? I think I need $\langle x,y \rangle$ to be real to apply the quadratic formula right? I suppose intuitively $\langle x,y \rangle $ must be real because there's no ordering on $\mathbb{C}$ so for the inequality to make sense it has to be real?

Maybe more importantly, does it even make sense to think of it as a quadratic because I'm using $|t|^2$ and $\overline{t}$ as the parameters?

Comment: this $\overline{t}\langle x,y \rangle = \overline{\overline{t}\langle x,y \rangle} $ is false for a sesquilinear product. What you have is that $\overline{t}\langle x,y \rangle = \bar t\overline{\langle y,x \rangle} $

Comment: Yeah i just realized as I was writing over but I can't figure out what the right approach is, trying to fix it now.

Comment: the usual proof decomposes $w$ in the product $\langle v,w \rangle $ as a sum of two orthogonal vectors, one of the form $rv$ for some $r\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: They are still equal though right @Masacroso, if I actually write out $t = \alpha+\beta i$ and $\langle x,y \rangle = a+bi$ then they do agree unless my arithmetic is wrong. Also is there a way to just modify my approach? We proved CS without leveraging orthogonality.

Comment: this $\overline{t}\langle x,y \rangle= t \langle y,x \rangle$ is still wrong. There you are assuming that $\bar zw=z\bar w$ for arbitrary complex numbers $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$, however if you took $z=1$ and $w=i$ you see that it cannot be true.

Comment: Yeah I just worked it out and saw my arithmetic was wrong. Is there any way to salvage this? Or I need to use orthogonality?

Comment: @AndreyYanyuk You may be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419667/when-the-equality-in-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-holds/4419685#4419685).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is
$$(x + ty, x + ty) = (x, x) + (ty, ty) + 2\Re((x, ty)) = \|x\|^2 + 2\Re(\bar{t}(x, y)) + |t|^2\|y\|^2.$$
If you want to apply calculus wrt $t$, then let's assume that $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we get
$$0 \leq (x + ty, x + ty) = \|x\|^2 + 2t\Re((x, y)) + t^2\|y\|^2.$$
Then, since this is a parabola that opens upward and is above the $x$-axis, it has at most one real zero, so
$$4\Re((x, y))^2 -4\|y\|^2\|x\|^2\leq 0,$$
i.e.
$$|\Re((x, y))| \leq \|x\|\|y\|.$$
Now for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha| = 1$, we can replace $x$ with $\alpha x$ to get
$$|\Re(\alpha(x, y))| \leq \|x\|\|y\|.$$
Cauchy's inequality comes from $\alpha = \frac{|(x, y)|}{(x, y)}$.

Comment: So what is this choie of $\alpha$ doing? Are we forcing $\langle x,y \rangle $ to be real?

Comment: $x, y$ are arbitrary elements of $V$. We choose $\alpha$ because it yields Cauchy's inequality when you plug it in. In fact, our choice of $\alpha$ maximizes the lhs.

Comment: @AndreyYanyuk You can also view the parabola trick as minimizing the rhs of the first inequality over $t$. So the entire proof consisted of introducing auxiliary parameters, getting inequalities involving the parameters,  and then choosing the parameters to get the best inequality.

Comment: Thanks its a lot clearer now. What do you think about assuming that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is strictly positive without loss of generality? Because if pick an $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $\langle x ,\alpha y \rangle$ is strictly positive, we have $|\langle x, \alpha y \rangle | = |\alpha| \langle x,y \rangle$ and $\sqrt{\langle \alpha y, \alpha y \rangle} = |\alpha| \sqrt{\langle y,y \rangle}$ so the addition of this $\alpha$ term has no bearing on the CS inequality? Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah that's essentially what I did. You are just introducing $\alpha$ earlier than I am. Your $\alpha$ is the complex conjugate of mine.

Comment: Ah I hadn't put it together! Thank you very much!